# Water damaged Nexus S turns on and runs but has unresponsive touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, water-damage

I dropped my Nexus S in water. I dried it out for a few days and the phone turns on to the home screen, and it seems to get the latest notifications although I cannot slide the phone and the touchscreen doesn't work.

Is there anything I can do from my computer, while phone is plugged in to get the touchscreen working again?

Comment: How'd you dry it out? Your work might not be done...

Comment: The Nexus S is rather easy to open and take apart ([iFixit howto here](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+S+Teardown/4365/1)). I'd suggest you do this or leave it for some more days. If that all doesn't help, you can get a replacement for the (EU) lcd (i9023) or (US) amoled (i9020) model on ebay (the pure panel+touch is cheaper but harder to reassemble (glue needed), they also sell the whole frontpanel (touch+screen+plastic-bordering+magnesium-chassis) as a whole (harder to find, more expensive but very easy to fix (2mins maybe)))

Answer (score 1):

If the hardware is water damaged, then no sorry.

It is quite possible that the device still has a small amount of liquid inside it - I suggest crushing some chalk, and placing the entire device into the crushed chalk (it absorbs moisture).

Otherwise, I am sorry to say that you would be quite stuck and would have to go to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

***Simplest Method.***

Place moisture-damaged device in zip-lock bag, with at least two tablespoons of white rice.

Store in warm place (hot water cupboard, or sunny nook), but **out of direct sunlight**, for two to three days.

Then all moisture will now be in rice, which you should discard (rather than consume).

---

**Note:** *Any attempt to use device, prior to complete removal of moisture, may have permanently damaged the device.*